# Write code (with special chars like \ or ") in variable

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

I have a script (`init.sh`) which create other scripts. So, in `init.sh` I want to have variables containing the other scripts. I use `read -d` to do that :

```
read -d '' script <<"EOF"
# Some code
sed -i "/PARALLEL_MAKE = \"-j 16\"/c\PARALLEL_MAKE = \"-j $threads\"" conf/local.conf
# Some code
EOF
echo "${script}" > script.sh
```

As you can see, I've commands with `\` and `"`. But, after running `init.sh`, in `script.sh` I have the corresponding line :

```
sed -i "/PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 16"/cPARALLEL_MAKE = "-j $threads"" conf/local.conf
```

The `\` aren't there.

I could try to escape special chars, unsing a lot of `\`. But my snippets of code are pretty big, and are used in other circumstances (with a simple copy-paste), so I'd like not to do that.

I could also put them in other files, but I can't. I want to do as described -- if possible.

Comment: I don't think that it answers your question but it's a lot more common to use `cat <<EOF >script.sh`, rather than `read` and `echo`. Do you want to interpolate the variables or not?

Comment: do you try to escape twice `\"` should be `\\\"` because the shell interpret it before giving it to sed. (sometime it need a third level so 1 `\ ` is complete by 4 previous one) and also, the `s` is missing from the action request `s///`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `read -r` to suppress the backslash escapes.